# What is the alternative for jsonp format in MVC core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to return result in `jsonp` format while I'm using `asp.net MVC Core`.
In asp.net MVC we can use `MVC.jsonp dll` an it's work fine but what is the alternative in MVC Core because I can't find any.

```
  public JsonpResult FunctionalitesTblList()
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        return Jsonp(Rows, settings);
    }
```

Comment: CORS to replace JSONP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

Answer (score 1):

There was no built in ability to handle JSONP with MVC, so you were always using a third-party addition. Apparently, that library is incompatible with .NET Core. Therefore, your option is to find a similar library that is compatible or choose some other approach.

@CuongLe is correct that CORS is a better approach overall, so you should definitely investigate that. However, if you insist on JSONP, it's so simple to implement manually, you don't really need a library.

Simply, all JSONP is a is JSON passed into a "callback" function, specified by the client. In other words, if the callack was specified as "mycallback", the response should just look like:

```
mycallback({ "foo": "bar" });
```

As a result, your code simply becomes:

```
string json = null;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{  
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Foo));  
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, foo);  
    json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());  
}
var jsonp = String.Format("{0}({1});", callback, json);
Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
return Content(jsonp);
```